# iptables resolved addresses differs from nslookup

Tags: iptables, dns

To block personal emails on a corporate network, I've blocked `FORWARD` to `mail.google.com` and `mail.live.com`. The following is how `iptables` resolved those addresses:

```
$  sudo iptables -L

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
Mail-Forward-Block  all  --  anywhere             anywhere         

Chain Mail-Forward-Block (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination            
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             lhr14s24-in-f5.1e100.net  reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             lhr08s07-in-f5.1e100.net  reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             origin.du113w.dub113.mail.live.com  reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             origin.du114w.dub114.mail.live.com  reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

`nslookup` for comparison (`192.168.0.10` is Samba running it's internal DNS and forwards lookups to `8.8.8.8`):

```
$ nslookup mail.google.com
Server:     192.168.0.10
Address:    192.168.0.10#53

Non-authoritative answer:
mail.google.com canonical name = googlemail.l.google.com.
Name:   googlemail.l.google.com
Address: 216.58.208.69

$ nslookup mail.live.com
Server:     192.168.0.10
Address:    192.168.0.10#53

Non-authoritative answer:
mail.live.com   canonical name = dispatch.kahuna.glbdns2.microsoft.com.
Name:   dispatch.kahuna.glbdns2.microsoft.com
Address: 157.56.195.156
Name:   dispatch.kahuna.glbdns2.microsoft.com
Address: 157.55.235.51
```

Obviously, that did not block anything. Re-adding the same rules somehow made the `iptable`'s addresses on par with `nslookup`. But why the difference at all? Can't we make `iptable` do reverse DNS lookup and check if it matches with those domains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No.  `iptables` rules affect IP addresses, not domain names.  That's why it's called iptables.

At the network layer where iptables operates, domain names are essentially irrelevant.  When you use a domain name with an iptables rule, a DNS lookup is performed and the domain name is resolved to an IP address, and the IP address at that particular moment in time is used in the rule.  If the domain is updated and the A record points to a different IP, iptables will know nothing about the change.

What you want to do (block certain web sites like gmail) is probably better done with a web proxy like `squid`.  This will allow you to log and monitor web usage, and there are add-ons like `squidguard` to help manage allow/deny lists.

If you want to block access to external smtp, then block the relevant ports (e.g. 25, 465, 587) to force local machines on the network to use your local smtp gateway - where you can control mail.

Comment: I've settled for using `--string mail.google.com` for the moment. But why does the rules show CNAMEs?